# Codeigniter Upload Not Working, Server Error 500

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter file upload isn't working. I have looked for answer in other question, but I met a server error.

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
     $this->load->library('upload');
  }

  public function index() { 
     $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' )); 
  } 

  public function do_upload() { 
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
     $config['max_size']      = 100; 
     $config['max_width']     = 1024; 
     $config['max_height']    = 768;  
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
     }

     else { 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
     } 
  } 
}
```

I tried to use this in my code aboves, and server error 500 happens.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

If I deleted that, all I saw "The upload path does not appear to be valid”.
Please Help.

Comment: Are you sure that `./uploads/` already exists and have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda nah, I don't know how to set permissions btw, but the folder exist in the root of my CI project

Comment: What is it? Linux?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda windows

Comment: try `$config['upload_path']   = APPPATH . 'uploads/';`.

Comment: Error is gone. But again. "Upload path doesn't appear to be valid"

Comment: So, it found the path, but can't write into.

Comment: So how to make the permissions?

Comment: How are you connecting to the server? SSH? FTP?

Comment: @Nvj I never touched what you said. I'm currently using codeigniter and mysql

Comment: Are you working off a server? How are you connecting to the server? You can connect to a server in different ways and depending on that you will be able to change directory permissions.

Comment: @Nvj my project web is not online, yet. But my teacher told to use SSH later.. My teacher has shown how to do upload. But somehow he missed it on github? Well, gonna ask him tomorrow.

Comment: If you're working from a local system, like from your own computer, just open the directory where you want to upload and change it's file permissions. If you are working off a local server, ask your teacher about it before making any changes.